# How to properly use the middle dot (·; 가운뎃점)?

Tags: formal, abbreviated, punctuation

I'm a native Korean speaker who's been off Korea for years. I've been binge watching American shows, studying in American high school, reading English books at the American library, and talking and making jokes in English.

Now, perhaps I will be going back to my home country soon. Since I'll be starting a Korean high school, I've tried to review my notes from Korea, but they've been thrown away. I have to know how to write the way I did back in time. One thing is that I extensively used the interpunct or the middle dot to shorten long names or list out similar/mutually exclusive items (I'm not meaning the bullet point). Now I've completely forgot how to use it. Please help me know.

---

한국인입니다. 요새 미국 프로그램을 보고, 미국에서 공부하고, 미국의 도서관에서 영어로 된 책을 보고, 영어로 대화하고 한지가 한국을 떠나 벌써 몇년째가 되었던 것인지 모르겠습니다. 이제 저는 한국으로 돌아가야 될지도 모릅니다. 한국에서 썼던 공책을 볼라고 했는데, 아 그게 버린지 오래더라고요.

그래서... 제가 가운뎃점을 쓰는 법을 완전히 까먹었습니다. 전에는 긴 이름을 줄이거나 뭐 비슷한 것들을 나열해서 쓸 때 (불렛포인트 아닙니다 아시죠?) 단어 가운데에 점을 찍어서 했던 것 같은데요- 저 진짜 모르는거 같애요. 도와주세요!

Answer (score 2):

According to *토픽 II 쓰기 100점 받자* (a TOPIK writing book), it says:

- 문장의 성분이 같은 것들을 여러 개 나타낼 때 씁니다. *(Writing lists in a sentence.)*

  - 예) 일본 · 영국 · 필니핀은 모두 섬나라이다. *(Japan, England, and the Philippines are all island countries.)*
- 특정한 의미를 가지는 날을 나타내는 숫자에 씁니다. *(Writing the numbers for a date with special meaning.)*

  - 예) 3·1운동, 8·15광복절 *(March 1st Movement, National Liberation Day of Korea)*

Answer (score 2):

The [standard usage](https://ko.wikisource.org/wiki/%EB%8C%80%ED%95%9C%EB%AF%BC%EA%B5%AD_%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80_%EB%A7%9E%EC%B6%A4%EB%B2%95(%EC%A0%9C2014-39%ED%98%B8)#5._.EA.B0.80.EC.9A.B4.EB.8E.83.EC.A0.90.28.E3.86.8D.29) is as follows:

> 5. 가운뎃점(ㆍ)
>
>    (1) 열거할 어구들을 일정한 기준으로 묶어서 나타낼 때 쓴다.
>
>    [예] 민수ㆍ영희, 선미ㆍ준호가 서로 짝이 되어 윷놀이를 하였다.
>      [예] 지금의 경상남도ㆍ경상북도, 전라남도ㆍ전라북도, 충청남도ㆍ충청북도 지역을 예부터 삼남이라 일러 왔다.
>
>    (2) 짝을 이루는 어구들 사이에 쓴다.
>
>    [예] 한(韓)ㆍ이(伊) 양국 간의 무역량이 늘고 있다.
>      [예] 우리는 그 일의 참ㆍ거짓을 따질 겨를도 없었다.
>      [예] 하천 수질의 조사ㆍ분석
>      [예] 빨강ㆍ초록ㆍ파랑이 빛의 삼원색이다.
>
>    다만, 이때는 가운뎃점을 쓰지 않거나 쉼표를 쓸 수도 있다.
>
>    [예] 한(韓) 이(伊) 양국 간의 무역량이 늘고 있다.
>         [예] 우리는 그 일의 참 거짓을 따질 겨를도 없었다.
>         [예] 하천 수질의 조사, 분석
>         [예] 빨강, 초록, 파랑이 빛의 삼원색이다.
>
>    (3) 공통 성분을 줄여서 하나의 어구로 묶을 때 쓴다.
>
>    [예] 상ㆍ중ㆍ하위권 
>      [예] 금ㆍ은ㆍ동메달
>      [예] 통권 제54ㆍ55ㆍ56호
>
>    [붙임] 이때는 가운뎃점 대신 쉼표를 쓸 수 있다.
>      [예] 상, 중, 하위권
>      [예] 금, 은, 동메달
>      [예] 통권 제54, 55, 56호

Answer (score 1):

The "·" (middle dot) symbol is known as an interpunct.

I assume you're asking about what is used for in English and Korean.

---

In English, although seemingly not commonly used, an interpunct can be used in formal (academic) papers for decimal points. I have not seen English speakers use interpuncts. I, as a native English speaker, do recognize that it can be mistaken for a bullet point and/or used for lists. Perhaps that is the interpunct's usage in English nowadays.

---

In Korean, I have seen it used in the place of a "/" (slash) symbol for listing word-choice options. If you see it in Korean text, I would assume it to be used like a slash.

> Example:
>
> Would you like pork/beef? -->
> 고기 / 쇠고기를 드시겠습니까? OR 고기 · 쇠고기를 드시겠습니까?

---

In your question, you described an interpunct being used to shorten words. I don't think that is how it can be used in either language. I think it is only used for listing word choice options; as the slash can be used for in English.

Answer (score 1):

https://ko.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EA%B0%80%EC%9A%B4%EB%8E%83%EC%A0%90

The link shows several different usages, although I'd personally divide it into two big segments:

1. To organize a list
2. To notate an important date (normally national holidays)

I generally see this punctuation with the second usage, though. The first one, I think, is rather formal and there rarely is a strong need for it in prose.

Answer (score -1):

한국어에서만 특별히 사용하는 것을 묻는 것이라면,
아래아로 사용합니다.

고어이자 사어입니다 (dead)

'ㅏ' 와 유사하게 발음합니다.

Comment: could you please elaborate what you're trying to say?

Comment: @user17915 http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=24651600

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was asking about

Comment: http://www.proz.com/kudoz/english_to_korean/linguistics/3783821-korean_vowel.html and the links there in have some explanation